# fontspec font-not-found / Invalid fontname on Mac update

Tags: xetex, fontspec, ebgaramond, macos

Over the past few years, I have had a rare but recurring problem where, when I typeset a document using EB Garamond, which I have installed on my Mac, I receive the following error:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))kpathsea:make_tex: Invalid fontname `EB Garamond', contains ' '
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
!
! The font "EB Garamond" cannot be found.
!
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
!
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................
```

This occurs even with a bare-bones MWE, and it occurs with completely updated software. It seems to only affect fonts installed locally, that is, in `/Users/moacir/Library/Fonts`. An example of the system profiler description of two culprit fonts is at the bottom.

It does not occur when I call `xelatex` from TeXShop, even though TeXShop uses the exact same path to TeXLive. It also does not seem to occur with system fonts, by which I mean fonts installed in `/System` or `/Library`. For example, if I have sections in Helvetica Neue, they appear in the pdf. The sections in EB Garamond are blank.

It seems that restarting the Mac when the problem occurs solves it, but I would rather not have to restart my computer every time the problem occurs.

Here is a general timeline since I [first asked about this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/343620/fontspec-error-font-not-found-with-xelatex-on-mac-sierra-10-2-and-texlive-2016) in December 2016:

- XeLaTeX was working fine whenever I’d use it throughout early 2017. I kept up with MacOS updates, but did not install TeXLive 2017.
- In mid-July, I used XeLaTeX to typeset an article I’m writing in EB Garamond. This is the last time I **know** I used the software from the command line.
- In late July, I updated my computer to 10.12.6 (with restart).
- On August 1, I start working on a new project involving TeX, and the error appears. I do not remember if I had used XeLaTeX since upgrading to 10.12.6.
- On August 2, I publish the first version of this question.
- I then update TeXLive to 2017 (vaguely thinking that solved the problem the last time I had it), and the problem continues.
- I restart the computer and the problem goes away.
- On August 4, the problem reappears. A restart makes it go away.
- On August 5, the problem reappears. A restart makes it go away.

The four (including in 2016) times I had this problem, they were solved once “by magic” and three times by a restart. I wish I had a more useful solution, however, than either of these two.

Currently, the system is running fine.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
\begin{document}
All human beings are born free and equal in dignity and rights.
\end{document}
```

Here are the font descriptions on my system both of two fonts that give trouble (HumboldtFraktur and EB Garamond):

> ```
> EBGaramond.otf:
>
>   Kind: OpenType
>   Valid: Yes
>   Enabled: Yes
>   Location: /Users/moacir/Library/Fonts/EBGaramond.otf
>   Typefaces:
>     EBGaramond:
>       Full Name: EB Garamond
>       Family: EB Garamond
>       Style: Regular
>       Version: Version 000.010
>       Unique Name: FontForge 2.0 : EB Garamond : 6-3-2011
>       Copyright: Created by Georg Duffner with FontForge 2.0 (http://fontforge.sf.net)
>       Outline: Yes
>       Valid: Yes
>       Enabled: Yes
>       Duplicate: No
>       Copy Protected: No
>       Embeddable: Yes
>
> HumboldtFraktur-Regular.ttf:
>
>   Kind: TrueType
>   Valid: Yes
>   Enabled: Yes
>   Location: /Users/moacir/Library/Fonts/HumboldtFraktur-Regular.ttf
>   Typefaces:
>     HumboldtFraktur:
>       Full Name: HumboldtFraktur
>       Family: HumboldtFraktur
>       Style: Regular
>       Version: Version 1.0; 2002; initial release
>       Unique Name: TypographerMediengestaltung: HumboldtFraktur: 2002
>       Designer: Dieter Steffmann
>       Copyright: Copyright (c) Typographer Mediengestaltung, 2002. All rights reserved. Humboldt-Fraktur geschaffen von Hiero Rhode, 1938. Digitalisiert und ergaenzt durch Dieter Steffmann, Kreuztal.
>       Description: Humboldt-Fraktur geschaffen von Hiero Rhode, 1938. Digitalisiert und ergaenzt durch Dieter Steffmann, Kreuztal.
>       Outline: Yes
>       Valid: Yes
>       Enabled: Yes
>       Duplicate: No
>       Copy Protected: No
>       Embeddable: Yes
> ```

Comment: Welcome! Shouldn't you be using current MacTeX with a Sierra system? (Not certain about this, but if OS changes need to be accommodated, a deprecated version isn't going to make those accommodations.)

Comment: You might also try removing the temporary directory where this stuff gets cached. `kpsewhich -var TEXMFVAR` will give you the path.

Comment: @cfr Thanks. Good point, and I meant to upgrade to 2017 before posting the question. I installed it, restarted, and now it works (it still didn't work before the restart, even though it was using the 2017 binaries). But it remains the case that it seemed to stop working on the upgrade from 10.12.5 to 10.12.6. But now the problem's disappeared…

Comment: @cfr texmfvar was empty, alas.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is resolved by updating to latest versions of software.

Comment: How are you loading the fonts; are you using file names or font names? If you are using font names make sure the Font Book application detects the fonts, i,e,, they appear in Font Book's font list.

Comment: I have voted to reopen because the issue was not resolved by updating to latest versions of software. The main thing that closing a question achieves is prevent anyone (now or in the future) who may have an answer from posting it, and I don't think that's something we need here.

Comment: If TEXMFVAR is really empty, that's odd unless you've just installed or not run LuaTeX, texdoc, anything which uses metafont fonts or .... This is possible, of course., if you really don't use anything of this kind.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR There's currently no evidence of the problem with current TL. Of course, the problem might occur with current software. But we have no reason to believe it will right now. The OP hasn't had the problem since installing TL 2017 (and restarting, which requirement is not unexpected).

Comment: @cfr did you read update2 at the top of the question?  The OP says it happened two times after it was "resolved", and I have no reason to disbelieve them. Do you? Of course it's probably something weird about their setup (which is why it doesn't affect more people),  but the nature of this site is that someone may come along eventually who has the same weird setup but can add more detail. And when they do, why actively prevent them from interacting here at this post? What is achieved by closing the question to do so?

Comment: I did read it, yes. Having read the question, updates and comments, I understood the OP to be saying that the issue was resolved even though it had recurred earlier. Earlier it was resolved mysteriously. This time, by updating and restarting. It really isn't weird to need to restart on a Mac, although it is less common than on Windows, I grant you. Maybe the question is just confusing me with all the different incidents and no real clarity.

Comment: here's a timeline, ignoring what happened last year in the previous question I asked: xelatex works fine, I upgrade MacOS, error appears. I update to TL 17, error persists. I restart. Error goes away. Next day, error returns. Restart and it goes away. Next day, error returns. Restart and it goes away. In other words, this problem has happened twice now w/ all new software.

Comment: How have you installed the problematic fonts (EB Garamond, Azuro, HumboldtFraktur) that you say are under User? And does the problem happen with other fonts under User? You can see the command-line tools mentioned at [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/35852/list-of-activated-fonts-with-shell-command-in-os-x) and [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/287707/get-list-of-all-fonts-containing-a-specific-character), and see what additional data they list about the problematic fonts?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR, Thanks. I installed the fonts using the FontBook app on the Mac. I picked those three fonts off the top of my head, but when the problem was happening, it *didn't* happen with system fonts (Helvetica Neue, Didot). Nothing from the font utilities jumps out at me. The fonts are listed as "Enabled: Yes" and "Valid: Yes," and they work in all other applications (and even work w/ fontspec most of the time). That's why this is so frustrating… It's not the case that it just doesn't work, full stop. It does, and then it doesn't, and then it does.

Comment: @Moacir I think it will be helpful if you post as full output about the fonts as possible, both when you don't have the problem (now) and when you do. In particular I'm interested in the "Location" field myself, but someone else may have better knowledge and know that it's some other field that matters. The more detail you add, the more likely someone will be able to figure it out, eventually.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR done. See the bottom of the OP. I hope that is useful.

Comment: Can you please edit your question so that it clearly reflects the current state of the problem? I don't mean the history isn't relevant, but get rid of notes saying the problem has gone away, when it hasn't. It may be an intermittent problem, but it is not helpful to have stuff saying 'when I had this problem ...'. You still have this problem, as I understand it. Also, focus on the TL 2017 case and just mention you had the same problem with 2016 and 2015. Right now, your question is just confusing. I voted to close because I honestly thought after reading your post quickly that it was no more.

Comment: Aren't you meant to restart a Mac after updating the OS? Or has Apple finally evolved a more civilised approach?

Comment: @cfr Done. Hopefully it's clearer now. Yes, I restarted when I installed the MacOS update back in July, and I may have restarted once or twice before the problem appeared. Since Aug 1, I have restarted three times, each time to clear up the font problem.

Comment: In my opinion, relying on system lookups for accessing fonts will rarely be 100% reliable in the long term. Although it's a great feature and allows people to experiment with fonts they already have installed in their OS, I recommend using a filename-based lookup and use a .fontspec feature file to specify which bold/italic fonts you would like to use.

Comment: @WillRobertson As the author of fontspec, you are probably the best person to answer this! Why do you say that font lookup by name (rather than filename) will not be reliable? Is there a way in which it might sometimes work and sometimes not? That would go some way towards explaining what's happening here. (BTW, having to write a `.fontspec` file contradicts what's on page 1 of the fontspec manual IMO: “Without fontspec, it is necessary to write cumbersome font definition files […] it becomes less desirable to have to write these font definition (.fd) files for every font one wishes to use.”)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR The font names are at first quite a mess. You only need to look in the luatex-font-names-file to see that every font has at least three slightly different names and you never know which one really works. Beside this it can easily happen that different fonts use the same name and then it is more or less luck to get the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

Following the recommendation by @WillRobertson, it seems like the answer, for now, is to avoid using fontspec's font finding abilities and change the MWE to read:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{EBGaramond}[
  Path = /Users/moacir/Library/Fonts/,
  UprightFont = * ,
  ItalicFont = *12-Italic ,
  SmallCapsFont = *SC ,
  Extension = .otf
  ]
\begin{document}
  All human beings are born free and equal in dignity and rights.
\end{document}
```

Note that the settings for ItalicFont and SmallCapsFont are consistent with what EB Garamond offers.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be relevant anymore, but I've struggled with the same problem on macOS using lualatex. For me, and the aforementioned combination, it was solved through `luaotfload-tool`, which is a part of the `luaotfload` -package ([CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/luaotfload)).

More specifically, running the following (sudo) fixed the problem:

```
luaotfload-tool --update
```

Jotting this down in case someone else has the same problem, finds this same question, and might be helped by this lua-solution.

Comment: this does not answer the question, at minimal, add how to use `luaotfload-tool` to solve the original problem

Comment: @jfbu Done. (I had the exact same error as reported by the op. For me, the problem was resolved as described.)

Comment: for the record I was once advised to do `luaotfload-tool --force --update -vvv --cache=purge`.

Comment: @jfbu I can imagine scenarios where that might be required. In my case, when running the tool it appeared there wasn’t even a database to begin with. (So no need for `—force`, in that case.)

Comment: not even a database? it is created on the first usage of lualatex on a document with fontspec

Comment: @jfbu That's what the output of `luaotfload-tool --update` said at any rate. However, as far as I could tell, everything else has been working fine -- except stuff involving TTC -fonts (like the op, this is on a Mac). But perhaps this conversation has wandered far enough beside the point, which simply was to write down a possible solution, if someone else had similar problems. (And evidently in vain, as it will soon be deleted by the looks of it. Oh well.)