# How to define a different font as the BoldFont in fontspec?

Tags: xetex, fontspec, ebgaramond

**Update**: I'm part of the way to a solution. This works:

```
\setmainfont{EBGaramond}[
  UprightFont = /Users/moacir/Library/Fonts/EBGaramond ,
  % Pick a system font that is also .otf:
  BoldFont = /System/Library/Fonts/SFNSDisplayCondensed-Thin ,
  Extension = .otf
]
```

So not using the `Path` option in fontspec is one way around this.

But if I remove the `Extension`, like this:

```
\setmainfont{EBGaramond}[
  UprightFont = /Users/moacir/Library/Fonts/EBGaramond.otf ,
  BoldFont = /System/Library/Fonts/SFNSDisplayCondensed-Thin.otf
]
```

This happens:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Could not map source abbreviation E for EBGaramond.
```

In other words, it can't find EBGaramond unless `Extension` is defined. But if I define it, then I can't use Helvetica Bold. It's not an `.otf`, but rather it's hiding inside `/System/Library/Fonts/Helvetica.dfont`.

Finally, if I change out EB Garamond for Humboldt Fraktur (`/Users/moacir/Library/Fonts/HumboldtFraktur-Regular.ttf`), I get a similar looking error, meaning EB Garamond is *not* responsible:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Could not map source abbreviation H for HumboldtFraktur-Regular
```

---

Because EB Garamond doesn't have a bold associated with it, the rare times I need a bold face, I use Helvetica Bold, instead. I used to do this:

```
\setmainfont[BoldFont={Helvetica Bold}]{EB Garamond}
```

This works great *as long as* the computer can find EB Garamond. When it can't, which seems to be [increasingly often](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384360/fontspec-font-not-found-invalid-fontname-on-mac-update), then I'm out of luck. But if I try:

```
\setmainfont{EBGaramond}[
  Path = /Users/moacir/Library/Fonts/,
  BoldFont = {Helvetica Bold} ,
  Extension = .otf
  ]
```

it looks for Helvetica inside the path I have defined:

```
kpathsea:make_tex: Invalid fontname `[/Users/moacir/Library/Fonts/Helvetica Bold.otf]/OT', contains '['
```

That's not where it is; it's a system-loaded font. How can I tell it to find Helvetica?

Comment: Why don't you use `Garamondx` or the recent `CormorantGaramond` for your bold font?

Comment: Mixing it with a bold is really an abuse of EB Garamond and should be reported to the International Society for the Protection of Font Faces. However, since the ISPFF does not yet exist, one of the options @Bernard suggests would surely be preferable. Why are you using EB Garamond in your personal set of fonts? Does FontBook not know about those installed as part of TeX Live? By the way, do you have the same problem with LuaTeX or is this XeTeX specific?

Comment: My question isn't EB Garamond specific. What if I wanted to use a locally installed font, Foo, as the main font and a system font, Bar, for the BoldFont? Is that possible, is what my question is asking.

Comment: @cfr I appreciate the aesthetic concern--the main reason I use "bold" is that section, etc, headings are put in bold, and I prefer those to be in a sans-serif font. As far as I can tell, Font Book does not see any TeX fonts (a search in the app for "computer modern" comes up blank). As for EB Garamond, I like it, and I don't see why any of the problems I have been having with it and fontspec are specific to the *font*, because I can recreate the exact error using other fonts. The problem is how fontspec sees user-installed fonts, imo.

Comment: Somewhat kludgy, but presumably workable: Create a symbolic link from the actual `Helvetica Bold` font file into the directory `/Users/moacir/Library/Fonts/` (or wherever the main font is located).

Comment: Incidentally, if the sans-serif bold font is to be used in section headers and the like, I suggest you look into acquiring the font `Palatino Sans`. Yes, there is such a font! It comes with regular and bold weights as well as upright and italic (slanted, really) shapes. All you would need for your document, I gather, is the **Bold/Upright** combo. Alternatives, which are probably already available on your system and thus free, would be `Myriad` and `Optima`.

Comment: You could always change your OS. `fontconfig` doesn't have this problem. But some might possibly consider this overkill.

Comment: @mico Thanks, but that doesn't address the problem that if I use the file name method of looking up the font (`EBGaramond.otf`, say), then it can't find it, but also can't use `Extension`, because the extension (`.otf`) is different from that of Helvetica, which is `.dfont`.

Comment: @Moacir - I think you may have to give up on the extension thing and just provide explicit filenames, including the extension parts.

Comment: @mico That's my point, however. That doesn't work, *either*. See my update above, from "But if I remove the `Extension`, like this:"

Comment: My previous comments are apparently entirely useless and unhelpful. Would you like me to delete them? Please advise.